# Kotlin Multiplatform - Google Admob

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I've been playing around with Kotlin Multiplatform and Compose Multiplatform and had a question on some libraries. Does anyone know if theres any ad services such as Google Admob or anything else that would work on KMM?

If there were no libraries and I had to implement on both platforms I'm not sure how I would make that work since all the UI is in the commons module

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you need to share UI you can use Compose for iOS, but it is in alpha now. 
https://youtu.be/FWVi4aV36d8
https://medium.com/@jacobras/android-ios-native-vs-flutter-vs-compose-multiplatform-7ef3d5ec2a56